# which version of Astyanax is compatible with Cassandra 2.0.1, Or which other Java drivers are compatible with Cassandra 2.0.1

Tags: cassandra, astyanax, java

I have installed Cassandra 2.0.1 and want to use Astyanax Java API's from my application.
I have seen the Cassandra compatibility table on the wiki which says

Astyanax uses a versioning scheme that is internal to Netflix and does not match the Cassandra versioning scheme. The below table provides a mapping from astyanax version to cassandra version.

**Astyanax                 Cassandra**

1.56.26 ... 1.56.34               1.1 - 1.2

1.0.4 ... 1.56.25             1.1

1.0.0 ... 1.0.3               1.0.8

... 0.8.11                    0.8.6

Here there is no mention of the compatibility of Cassandra 2.0.1 with Astyanax.
1.  I would like to know the version of Astyanax is compatible with Cassandra 2.0.1.
2. Or Should I use some other APIs, Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datastax java driver](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.cassandra%7Ccassandra-driver-core%7C2.0.0-beta1%7Cjar) is compatable with C* 2.0.x but it's still in beta.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

As for astyanax, they [dont have an official release](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cassandra-compatibility) that supports 2.0 quite yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As we are new to Cassandra we had picked the latest release of 2.0.0 but we were not finding the Java drivers. We have now moved to Cassandra 1.2 with Datastax Java driver 1.0.3.

Comment: There is now an official release of the driver. See http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C679835382 (Current version is 2.1.2)